# Alt+Tab replacement for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

A number of different Alt+Tab switcher replacement apps have been developed for XP, such as [TaskSwitchXP](http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp.html). I've also written one of my own, which I've used for years. Unfortunately, I've found that on Windows 7 these tools don't work anymore. The problem is that they can no longer register Alt+Tab as a hotkey, because it's already registered (presumably by Explorer). As best I can tell, on XP the default switcher did not use the regular [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) API, but now it does.

Does anybody know of a workaround for this, or an Alt+Tab replacement that works on Windows 7? I know they've spiffed up the default one and added the 3D flip switcher (Win+Tab), but I'd still like to be able to replace this with something that works better for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) before, and it works pretty well.  Requires Aero and is more of a replacement for Flip3D than the traditional Alt+Tab. Does keyboard context searching, too.

Answer (score 6):

Another candidate is [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html), from the same person that created [TaskSwitchXP](http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp.html).

Internally, the trick seems to be that you have to use a low-level keyboard hook to listen for Alt+Tab, instead of registering it as a hotkey (since you won't be able to do so on Win7).

Answer (score 3):

I've recently came across a lightweight and minimalistic [Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo) on GitHub, the latest development of it, as done by [Regin Larsen](https://github.com/kvakulo), and immediately switched to it as the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> replacement.

[image: Switcheroo Screenshot]

As seen in the screenshot above taken from its page on GitHub, the tasks are listed in a simple format by title and the executable starting the task.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> navgiates and <kbd>enter</kbd> switches, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes the window.

---

The switching is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default but can be changed in settings,

more specifically in the XML configuration file located inside its installation folder,

that is in `%programfiles%` (`%programfiles(x86)%` if you're on 64-bit edition of Windows)`

inside `switcheroo.exe.config` file by setting `AltTabHook`'s value to `True` as shown below:

```
<setting name="AltTabHook" serializeAs="String">
<value>True</value>
</setting>
```

It's the most efficient replacement I've ever tried, and am very happy to <s>get rid of Window's default Task Switcher Application</s> use it.

Added screenshots to aid with locating:

[image: Inside the folder]

[image: Inside the XML file]

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Dexpot-Virtual Desktop](http://dexpot.de/). It does alot of stuff and is free and highly customizable.