# Flat mosaic view of all windows (similar to ALT+TAB / WIN+TAB)

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

*Note: Linked to [Alt+Tab replacement for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/43842/alttab-replacement-for-windows-7) but not a duplicate, here the requirement is more specific, see below.*

On Windows 7, I know <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, the latter giving a 3D view like:

[image: Aero flip 3D]

**How to have a flat (and not 3D) mosaic / grid of all open windows?**
without having to do something like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and then hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>? In a similar way than Mac four fingers swipe "Mission Control":

[image: Mission control]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alt+Tab replacement for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/43842/alttab-replacement-for-windows-7)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It's definitely linked, but my question is more specific to a specific behaviour similar to Mac Mission Control (flat 2D mosaic of all apps, *without* holding a key).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the list of windows without holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> then why don't just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

- [What is the difference between pressing Alt+Tab and Ctrl+Alt+Tab?](https://superuser.com/q/1517448/241386)
- [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I finally found a simple solution with AutoHotkey:

```
~RCtrl:: AltTabMenu
```

This displays a 2D grid (like if we hold ALT+TAB) permanently, until we click on a thumbnail, when pressing on right <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.